# Does anyone have c# code to use betfair api?

Tags: c#, betfair

I am creating a c# windows app to display current sports market rates using betfair exchange webservice, I used the

> getmarketpricescompressed()

method which returns a price string that looks like this:

```
106093239~GBP~ACTIVE~0~1~~true~5.0~1343114432333~~N:7337~1~6992.56~2.16~~~false~~~~|2.16~1036.19~L~1~2.14~97.18~L~2~2.12~5.0~L~3~|2.18~467.36~B~1~2.2~34.12~B~2~2.22~162.03~B~3~:414464~2~102181.96~1.86~~~false~~~~|1.85~2900.33~L~1~1.84~1831.59~L~2~1.83~1593.73~L~3~|1.86~58.83~B~1~1.87~1171.77~B~2~1.88~169.15~B~3~
```

i don't know how to properly unpack this string, for now i am using this code:

```
GetMarketPricesCompressedReq price_req1 = new GetMarketPricesCompressedReq();
            price_req1.header = header2;
            price_req1.marketId = marketid_temp;
            price_req1.currencyCode = "GBP";
            GetMarketPricesCompressedResp price_resp = new GetMarketPricesCompressedResp();
            price_resp = bfg2.getMarketPricesCompressed(price_req1);
            //MessageBox.Show(price_resp.errorCode.ToString());
            //richTextBox1.Text = "";
            //richTextBox1.Text = price_resp.marketPrices;
            string prices = price_resp.marketPrices;
            richTextBox1.Text = price_resp.marketPrices;
            string[] ab1 = prices.Split('|');
            string[] temp = ab1[1].Split('~');
            textBox3.Text = temp[0];
            textBox4.Text = temp[4];
            textBox5.Text = temp[8];
            temp = ab1[2].Split('~');
            textBox6.Text = temp[0];
            textBox7.Text = temp[4];
            textBox8.Text = temp[8];
            temp = ab1[3].Split('~');
            textBox9.Text = temp[0];
            textBox10.Text = temp[4];
            textBox11.Text = temp[8];
            temp = ab1[4].Split('~');
            textBox12.Text = temp[0];
            textBox13.Text = temp[4];
            textBox14.Text = temp[8];
            if (ab1.Length >5)
            {
                temp = ab1[5].Split('~');
                textBox15.Text = temp[0];
                textBox16.Text = temp[4];
                textBox17.Text = temp[8];
                temp = ab1[6].Split('~');
                textBox18.Text = temp[0];
                textBox19.Text = temp[4];
                textBox20.Text = temp[8];
            }
```

It works fine for a few matches, but i observed the string changes for a few other matches and it thus generates exceptions,
Can any1 help me with a proper code to unpack this string, i've googled it and found a vb code, which was not very usefull,

and btw, i want to arrange the data in something like this:

[image]

Comment: The method returns a price string that looks like a long google URL?

Comment: oh gosh, m sorry, that was a mistake, i corrected it for real :3

Comment: What was wrong with the (presumably) VB.NET code? If it really was VB.NET it's rather easily convertible to C# with a little knowhow. =) Also, consider posting your second question as an actual second question. =)

Comment: Also - what does the documentation say for that particular method's return values? I'm sure it describes any sort of dynamic content available to you. =)

Comment: Actually the vb code was for unpacking a similar method string, and i don't understand it well....:/
I need to use this method only, as instructed by my lead :|

Comment: @J.Steen: the documentation just says that "Back/Lay Prices then delimited by a | (pipe), 0 or more iterations"
It does'nt gives any algo to extract the data

Comment: Well, you have an unknown number of price-sequences, yet you're accessing them directly by index. Try going at this with a more iterative approach, looking at each pipe-delimited chunk separately. =)

Comment: It seems to me the data is delimited into rows first by `":"` first, the first row being the header. Then each row is seperated into a kind of Selection ID, Lays and Backs by the `"|"` delimiter. Don't betfair document this, perhaps somewhere here. I can't look, its deemed NSFW. https://docs.developer.betfair.com

Comment: It does, actually - there's a fairly comprehensive breakdown of the entire string in the documentation here: https://docs.developer.betfair.com/betfair/#!page=00008360-MC.00008307-MC

Comment: @Jodrell:  i've already been through that documentation, not helpfull,
well this is the vb code i was talking about, can some1 help me convert it....pleeeesssssee....:/
http://forum.bdp.betfair.com/showpost.php?p=762&postcount=60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing, I think the data is organised like this

first delimited by `:` then `|` we get

> 106093239~GBP~ACTIVE~0~1~~true~5.0~1343114432333~~N
>
> 7337~1~6992.56~2.16~~~false~~~~
>   2.16~1036.19~L~1~2.14~97.18~L~2~2.12~5.0~L~3~
>   2.18~467.36~B~1~2.2~34.12~B~2~2.22~162.03~B~3~
>
> 414464~2~102181.96~1.86~~~false~~~~
>   1.85~2900.33~L~1~1.84~1831.59~L~2~1.83~1593.73~L~3~
>   1.86~58.83~B~1~1.87~1171.77~B~2~1.88~169.15~B~3~

I think that first row is clearly a header, that first number being the market ID perhaps.
Likewise, the first part of each subsequent section is a row identifier. Delimited by `~` something like

> (SelectionId)7337 (Order)1 (TotalMatched?)6992.56 (EvenPoint)2.16 (???)false

I think the price rows are delimited by `~` in tuples of 4, like this

> (Price)2.16 (MatchAvailable)1036.19 (Type)L (Order)1
>   (Price)2.14 (MatchAvailable)0097.18 (Type)L (Order)2
>   (Price)2.12 (MatchAvailable)0005.00 (Type)L (Order)3

for example.

To test my guesses I'd have to compare with the BetFair rendering on thier web site.

Comment: Clearly that is as near as it could be with the original data shown on the website, the (Price) and (MatchAvailable) are as shown on the website,

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
a|b|c|d
```

In this, you have four chunks. But it doesn't necessarily have to be only four. It can be two, it can be six.

Try going at it by iterating the string-array you get as a result of the

```
string[] ab1 = prices.Split('|');
```

Something like

```
foreach(var stringChunk in ab1)
{
    string[] temp = stringChunk.Split('~');
    // use the strings here as you please
}
```

Consider using a more dynamic approach in presenting your data as well, using a row-based, repeating control instead of static textboxes. =)

The full documentation for the compressed data is available here: https://docs.developer.betfair.com/betfair/#!page=00008360-MC.00008307-MC

Comment: well this seems legit, but what if i had to display the parsed data on labels, then i would have to generate and position those labels dynamically......but i guess it's worth a shot....thanxx

Answer (score 2):

I converted the vb code to c# myself, if anyone might find it useful, I am posting it here:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace stock
{
    class UnpackMarketPricesCompressed : stock.BFExchangeService.MarketPrices
{
        //The substitute code for "\:"
    private const string ColonCode = "&%^@";

    //Unpack the string
    public UnpackMarketPricesCompressed(string MarketPrices)
    {
        string[] Mprices = null;
        string[] Part = null;
        string[] Field = null;
        int n = 0;

        Mprices = MarketPrices.Replace("\\:", ColonCode).Split(':');
        //Split header and runner data
        Field = Mprices[0].Replace("\\~", "-").Split('~');
        //Split market data fields
        marketId = Convert.ToInt32(Field[0]);
        //Assign the market data
        currencyCode = Field[1];
        marketStatus = (stock.BFExchangeService.MarketStatusEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(stock.BFExchangeService.MarketStatusEnum), Field[2], true);
        delay = Convert.ToInt32(Field[3]);
        numberOfWinners = Convert.ToInt32(Field[4]);
        marketInfo = Field[5].Replace(ColonCode, ":");
        discountAllowed = (Field[6].ToLower() == "true");
        marketBaseRate = float.Parse(Field[7]);
        lastRefresh = long.Parse(Field[8]);
        removedRunners = Field[9].Replace(ColonCode, ":");
        bspMarket = (Field[10] == "Y");

        n = Mprices.Length - 1;
         // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement

        //For each runner
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) 
        {
            Part = Mprices[i + 1].Split('|');
            //Split runner string into 3 parts
            Field = Part[0].Split('~');
            //Split runner data fields
             runnerPrices[i] = new stock.BFExchangeService.RunnerPrices();
            var _with1 = runnerPrices[i];
            //Assign the runner data
            _with1.selectionId = Convert.ToInt32(Field[0]);
            _with1.sortOrder = Convert.ToInt32(Field[1]);
            _with1.totalAmountMatched = Convert.ToDouble(Field[2]);
            _with1.lastPriceMatched = Convert.ToDouble(Field[3]);
            _with1.handicap = Convert.ToDouble(Field[4]);
            _with1.reductionFactor = Convert.ToDouble(Field[5]);
            _with1.vacant = (Field[6].ToLower() == "true");
            _with1.farBSP = Convert.ToDouble(Field[7]);
            _with1.nearBSP = Convert.ToDouble(Field[8]);
            _with1.actualBSP = Convert.ToDouble(Field[9]);
            _with1.bestPricesToBack = Prices(Part[1]);
            _with1.bestPricesToLay = Prices(Part[2]);
        }
    }

    private stock.BFExchangeService.Price[] Prices(string PriceString)
    {
        string[] Field = null;
        stock.BFExchangeService.Price[] Price = null;
        int k = 0;
        int m = 0;

        Field = PriceString.Split('~');
        //Split price fields
        m = (Field.Length / 4) - 1;
        //m = number of prices - 1 
         // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement

        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) 
        {
            Price[i] = new stock.BFExchangeService.Price();
            var _with2 = Price[i];
            _with2.price = Convert.ToInt32(Field[k + 0]);
            //Assign price data
            _with2.amountAvailable = Convert.ToInt32(Field[k + 1]);
            _with2.betType = (stock.BFExchangeService.BetTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(stock.BFExchangeService.BetTypeEnum), Field[k + 2], true);
            _with2.depth = Convert.ToInt32(Field[k + 3]);
            k += 4;
        }
        return Price;
        //Return the array of prices
    }

    }
}
```